# Repeatedly add text to div element

Tags: javascript, html

Using Javascript, I would like to repeatedly add the same text over and over again to the same div element.

```
<script>
    while(true) {
        var itstimeto = document.getElementById("duel");   
        var d = "D-";
        itstimeto.innerHTML = itstimeto + d;
        itstimeto = document.getElementById("duel");
    }
</script>
<div id="duel">IT'S TIME TO </div>
```

However, the div just stays at the text "IT'S TIME TO " with nothing being added onto the text.

My only explanation is that the variable is being repeatedly defined over and over again.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Infinite loop much?

Comment: Maybe try `itstimeto.innerHTML = itstimeto.innerHTML + d;`

Comment: Hard to show this with a code snippet. ;) *Note: what you're trying to do is pointless, page will never load this way, at least try using setInterval so that you can actually see whats going on.*

Answer (score 0):

```js
itstimeto.innerHTML = itstimeto + d;
```

Probably should be

```js
 itstimeto.innerHTML = itstimeto.innerHTML + d;
```

Answer (score 0):

First remove infinite loop.

Second use below code

```js
while() {
  var itstimeto = document.getElementById("duel");   
  var d = "D-";
  itstimeto.innerHTML = itstimeto.innerHTML + d;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As @clarmond said in his comments, you want to do `itstimeto.innerHTML = itstimeto.innerHTML + d;` for getting the inner text and appending further text.

Also I don't see the use of mapping the variable to the same element.

here's the script you need. Just a fair warning that your code might cause you serious trouble when you run it due to the infinite loop you are running

```
while(true) {
    var itstimeto = document.getElementById("duel");   
    var d = "D-";
    itstimeto.innerHTML = itstimeto.innerHTML + d;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**1.)** Change `itstimeto.innerHTML = itstimeto + d` to `itstimeto.innerHTML = itstimeto.innerHTML + d;`

**2.)** Try change `while (true)` to `setInterval`, because while is freeze entire page.

So final code can look like this:

```
setInterval(function(){ 
var itstimeto = document.getElementById("duel");   
        var d = "D-";
        itstimeto.innerHTML = itstimeto.innerHTML + d;
}, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove these lines :

```
   var d = "D-";
   itstimeto.innerHTML = itstimeto + d;
   itstimeto = document.getElementById("duel");
```

Change to:

```
 var d = document.createTextNode('D-');
itstimeto.append(d);
```

Those are vanilla JS methods, not going to explain.  Reference https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript for more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Try using += in order to concatenate your strings.
https://plnkr.co/edit/RPUmE7?p=preview

```
<button onclick="run()">RUN</button>
  <div id="msg">Hello world!</div>    
// Code goes here

    function run() {
      var finalMessage = [] ;
      var msg = document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML;
      for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
          finalMessage.push(msg + " D- <br>");
      }
      document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = finalMessage.join('');
    }
```